# More than one textarea giving me problems

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm using Bootstrap with *Laravel 4.2.*  Whenever I try to add more than 1 textarea to my form, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'comment'
>   cannot be null

I have isolated the problem to be that whichever textarea I allow to be first, no matter what variable name I give it or how I try to save it, only the first textarea content gets saved and the others get "null" when I try to read it in using `Input::get('my_textarea_name');`

Here's a snipped of my form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'course_review', 'id'=>'clearForm'))}}
       <div class="row">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="course_comment">How can students succeed in this course?</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="course_comment" name="course_comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="row">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="assignments_comment">What kind of assignments and tests did this course have?</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="assignments_comment" name="assignments_comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="row">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="prerequisites_comment">What skills and prerequisites are required for this course?</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="prerequisites_comment" name="prerequisites_comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info ladda-button" data-style="zoom-out" id="create_or_edit_button"><span class="ladda-label">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add this review</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's a snipped from my Model:

```
$review = new Review();
$review->course_comment = Input::get('course_comment');
$review->assignments_comment = Input::get('assignments_comment');
$review->prerequisites_comment = Input::get('prerequisites_comment');
$review->save();
```

I was just wondering if anyone is aware of this or knows of a way around it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code (like your form and where you try to save the register)?

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have nested forms.

```
{{ Form::open(...)}}
    <form role="form">
    ...
    </form>
    <form role="form">
    ...
    </form>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

You should get rid of all those `<form role="form">...</form>`. They are doing nothing and they break HTML standard. Your browser gets confused and only submits one of them at a time. Hence you get `null` in the not submited ones. You can have several forms in a page but they should not be nested.

From the [html5 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element):

> **4.10.3 The `form` element**
>
> **Content model:**
>
> Flow content, but with no form element descendants.

Comment: Thanks Javi - somehow I missed seeing your answer this morning and posted my own, but I accepted yours when I saw it was posted 10 hours ago!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to insert a null value into the `comment` field of your table.
just make sure it isn't null.

It's pretty obvious that cause of this error is empty value of `comment`

```
$review = new Review();
$review->course_comment = Input::get('course_comment' ,false);
$review->assignments_comment = Input::get('assignments_comment', false);
$review->prerequisites_comment = Input::get('prerequisites_comment', false);
$review->save();
```

Comment: replace with this code.See you dose't allow null value in your respective fields.

Comment: Thanks jigs, but the problem seems to be that the text that gets inputted into the textarea does not get read by the Input::get('assignments_comment', false); or the Input::get('prerequisites_comment', false); only the first one gets the text input from the form successfully.  The second two get null even when I enter text in the textarea!

Comment: have you try with define with array like <textarea name="comment[0]"></textarea>, <textarea name="comment[1]"></textarea>, <textarea name="comment[2]"></textarea>. in your controller $dataArray = $_POST['data'];

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  I'm not sure it will work with Laravel, but I'll play around with it and see.

Comment: Ok awesome I will try it tomorrow and accept your answer if it works.  Thanks.  Any idea why more than one textarea is screwing my form over?

Comment: Before few days I had same problem.I solve with this but I could not found reason behind this.

Comment: I think that was a really smart attempt.  However, it did not work for me.  The first textarea still was read successfully, but the 2nd one gave an "undefined index" error!  I can't believe it.  You got more than one textarea to be successfully read from the same form?

Answer (score 0):

So... after a lot of pain, I just figured out the answer to my own question.  Hopefully this will help someone else who makes the same mistake.  In the code I originally posted, you will see I had wrapped each of my textareas in its own `<form role="form">` wrapper:

```
<div class="row">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="assignments_comment">What kind of assignments and tests did this course have?</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="assignments_comment" name="assignments_comment"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<hr>
```

This was the source of the problem, as it prevented textareas #2 and #3 from getting read.  I'm surprised the first textarea was getting read, in fact.  Removing the extra  wrappers allowed me to submit more than one textarea successfully.  There should be only 1  wrapper for a form.  I had copied and pasted this code directly from w3c so it took me a while to realize multiple copies of part of the code would cause me an error.